# iframe responsive issues with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `iframe` with Bootstrap, and it is not responsive in <768px as it goes off screen.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="text-center">
            <iframe src="http://www.emanueleferonato.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/wheel/" width = "458" height = "488" frameborder = "0" scrolling = "no"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your provided code you are specifying absolute values for the `height` and `width` of your `<iframe>`.  Absent any additional media queries to modify these values you *won't* have any responsiveness.

If you were using Bootstrap 4 you could make use of the `embed-responsive` class, which specifically addresses your concerns here.  For Bootstrap 3 you'll likely want to create your own class:

```
.responsive-iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 75vh; // Change this based on your own preferences
}
```

And then apply it to your `<iframe>`

`<iframe src= "/path/" class="responsive-iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

At this point your embed would take up 100% of the width of its parent container, and have a minimum height of 75% of the viewport height.  I would note that this '75vh' is just for the purposes of allowing a minimum display for presentation.  You'll likely need to adjust this for your specific project.

If you're considering transitioning to Bootstrap 4 you can read more about their embed class here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any responsive styles on your iframe. You are currently assigning static height and width styles. Look at the documentation for Bootstrap 4, it has a built-in responsive class for iframes, something like this:

```
<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Or you could make your own class:

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Also might be useful to consider assigning the styles "overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: visible" in case the content in the iframe is not able to be accurately displayed in the space you gave it.